# How to configure IIS 7.5 to handle .ptx file format?

Tags: perl, iis-7.5

I'm trying to load a function in a web server and I'm receiving this error

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

From my knowledge it's due to the fact that .plx format is not configured in the handler mapping

I've done research and found a way to configure the .pl and Perl format

But I can't find something that helps me configuring the .plx format

Any help is appreciated

Best regards

Comment: Why can't you add a script map for `*.plx` files the same way you added a script map for `*.pl` files?

Comment: @MattJacob I will try to do what your suggesting , maybe the file contains library to run the .plx . but First of all thank you for the edit , it make my question more clear . After all , I have no knowledge so I follow this tutorial http://www.howtogeek.com/50479/how-to-install-perl-on-iis-7-for-windows-server-2008/

Comment: Right, so you're running in the CGI environment, as I suspected. Just add another script map for `*.plx` with the same settings you used for the other Perl file extensions.

Comment: @MattJacob Thank you ! I will try that out

Comment: @MattJacob thanks ! it seens to work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Matt advice , I added a script map for *.plx files the same I added a script map for *.pl files , and it seems to work !